# why the TypeToken construction in Gson is so weird?

Tags: java, json, constructor, gson

When I use Gson to parse between object and json, the initialization of a TypeToken is so weird:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
```

I just know this kind of format: `new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>().getType();`, what's the braces in above for? Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I've looked into the source code of `TypeToken` class, it is a `class`(not interface or abstract) and without any constructor, which means it uses `no-parameter constructor` as default.

**P.S.2** When I delete the braces, it tell me that the constructor is not visible. When I looked inside the TypeToken class, this is the constructor:

```
  protected TypeToken() {
        this.type = getSuperclassTypeParameter(getClass());
        this.rawType = (Class<? super T>) $Gson$Types.getRawType(type);
        this.hashCode = type.hashCode();
  }
```

Why doesn't it just use `public` instead?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

'Weird' is not exactly a technical term. The class is defined in such a way as to force you to explicitly specify a generic parameter to be associated with a concrete instance of it. Because compiled Java classes retain information about their generic parameters that information then becomes available to framework libraries that require it.

That's the very purpose of a super type token.

Comment: Thanks, another question: what if changing the default constructor from `protected` to `public`, when initializing `TypeToken`, we still need to specify the generic to `Collection<Integer>`, why can't the TypeToken instance be aware of the type of Collection<Integer> in this senario?

Comment: Well, actually, having the constructor protected is essential. It prevents people from being able to do `TypeToken<Whatever> t = new TypeToken<Whatever>();`, which would defeat the whole purpose of the class. As it is, you are *forced* to actually subclass in order to fully define the token, which is what the designers intend. You can think of the whole thing as a hack to get around the fact that Java implements generics via type-erasure. Hope that makes things more clear.

Comment: So this is the point: If I use `TypeToken<Whatever> t = new TypeToken<Whatever>();`, according to the generics mechanism, I cannot get any type information about `Whatever`; whereas if I subclass the TypeToken using `TypeToken<Whatever> t = new TypeToken<Whatever>(){};`, I can get the type information about `Whatever`? Am I right?

Comment: @Perception the wording of "compiled Java classes retain information about their generic parameters" is misleading. In fact, that statement is false for _all_ classes except anonymous ones. http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 7):

`new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}` means you are creating an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends `TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>`. Also at the same time you are creating an instance of that anonymous class.

From the link:

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

Answer (score 3):

[TypeToken](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.java?r=2) is abstract, so you have to create a concrete class to instantiate it, that's why you have the `{}`.

This code create the concrete anonymous subclass, instantiate it then calls `getType` on the instance.

Comment: sorry, TypeToken is not `abstract`. This is the declaration: `public class TypeToken<T> {...}`.

Comment: Well, not in all versions. See the link in my answer : `public abstract class TypeToken<T> {`

Comment: I see.. but how to explain for my version, the default constructor is `protected`, what does the braces do in this senario? So the brace can use for a `non-abstact class` just for create a `anonymous class`? Thanks bro.

Comment: That the constructor is protected serves the same purpose as it being abstract: You HAVE to subclass it to make use of it. With is the entire point.